# Extraer string por coincidencia de letras

Tags: python

espero que estén bien
Tengo la siguiente duda:

En el siguiente ejemplo, me gustaria extraer los códigos que parten por **R20**, ya que pueden ser **R2020** o **R2019**, asi que prefiero dejarlo solo con **R20** y tener algún código que me extraiga el código completo.

Muchas gracias!

Listado de ejemplo:

```
reclamos=list(df.descripcion_inconformidad)
reclamos
['CONSUMIDORA INFORMA QUE PROVEEDOR NO HA DADO CUMPLIMIENTO A SU RECLAMO N? R2019W3378330',
 'QUISIERA INFORMAR INCUMPLIMIENTO DEL PROVEEDOR A RESPUESTA ENTREGADA A RECLAMO R2020W3497628. A LA FECHA DE HOY 11 DE FEBRERO DEL 2020, AUN NO ME REEMBOLSAN MI DINERO.',
 'Caso R2019W3353739, aun no me entregan lo que compre el 08/10/2019. Voy a cumplir 3 meses esperando que me despachen.',
 'CONSUMIDOR INDICA QUE PROVEEDOR A UN NO DA CUMPLIMENTO A RESPUESTA DEL CASO N ?R2020M3458452',
 'CONSUMIDOR INDICA INCUMPLIMIENTO DE PARTE DEL PROVEEDOR R2020M3454327 YA QUE SIGUEN REALIZANDO LLAMADAS A LOS NUMEROS INDICADOS EN EL RECLAMO .',
 'CONSUMIDORA INDICA QUE PROVEEDOR NO HA DADO CUMPLIMIENTO A SU RECLAMO N? R2019W3426996, NO HA REALIZADO DEVOLUCION DEL DINERO',
 'QUISIERA INFORMAR INCUMPLIMIENTO POR PARTE DEL PROVEEDOR A LA RESPUESTA ENTREGADA A RECLAMO R2020W3453134. ME COMUNIQUE EL 31 DE ENERO PARA COORDINAR LA ENTREGA Y ME RESPONDIERON QUE ESTA NO SE REALIZARIA.',
 'ACUSA QUE SKYAIRLINE NO CUMPLE RESOLUCION R2019M3368020',
 'Consumidora acusa incumplimiento en relacion a la respuesta entregada al reclamo R2019M3418991',
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes utilizar una regex para conseguir los códigos, iterando sobre el listado donde tengas cada frase. Específicamente, puedes utilizar la función `search()` del módulo `re`, dentro de una comprehensión de lista.

```
import re


reclamos = [
    'CONSUMIDOR INDICA QUE PROVEEDOR A UN NO DA CUMPLIMENTO A RESPUESTA DEL CASO N ?R2020M3458452',
    'CONSUMIDOR INDICA INCUMPLIMIENTO DE PARTE DEL PROVEEDOR R2019M3454327 YA QUE SIGUEN REALIZANDO LLAMADAS A LOS NUMEROS INDICADOS EN EL RECLAMO .',
    'CONSUMIDORA INDICA QUE PROVEEDOR NO HA DADO CUMPLIMIENTO A SU RECLAMO N? R2019W3426996, NO HA REALIZADO DEVOLUCION DEL DINERO'
]
codes = [re.search('R20[A-Z0-9]+', sentence).group() for sentence in reclamos]
print(codes)
```

**output**

```
['R2020M3458452', 'R2019M3454327', 'R2019W3426996']
```

---

**EDICIÓN**

Por favor, ten en cuenta que el código que te he proveído funcionará únicamente si dentro de la lista `reclamos` todas las oraciones contienen un código como el que estás interesado en extraer (que empiece con 'R20').

En caso de que no sea así, usa el siguiente código:

```
import re


codes = [re.search('R20[A-Z0-9]+', sentence).group()
        for sentence in reclamos if 'R20' in sentence]
```

Comment: Muchas gracias para ti también !!!, probaré con el método que me indicas :D

Comment: Sabes, intenté y me sale esto: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: Ese error sucede cuando la función `search()` no encuentra nada de acuerdo al patrón especificado. Asegúrate de estar replicando bien el código que te proporcioné, tal cual como lo hice, ya que en efecto ese patrón de regex funciona para las oraciones que están dentro de esa lista (`list_`). Por favor, asegúrate bien de estar adaptando el código correctamente.

Comment: Si, si lo repliqué tal cual
El único cambio que hice fue que, la variable list_ en mi caso es una columna que se llama así : reclamos=list(df.descripcion_inconformidad)
Cuando reemplazo list_ por reclamos, sale el error que te digo

Comment: Okay, ¿podrías, por favor, actualizar tu pregunta y colocar cómo luce tu lista `reclamos`? Así le echo un ojo y puedo ver cuál es la diferencia que puede estar causando el error.

Comment: Listo, actualizado el código!

Comment: Incluso con la lista que proveíste, el patrón que te compartí sigue funcionando. Mis sospechas es que dentro de la lista `reclamos` deben haber strings que no contienen algún código. Correcto? Editaré mi respuesta para dar una alternativa en ese caso.

Comment: Hola Reviliscano!, sabes, intenté con el código que me dejaste pero me sigue saliendo 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
El listado de los reclamos es el mismo de la pregunta, y el código que usé fue:

codes = [re.search('R20[A-Z0-9]+', sentence).group()for sentence in reclamos if 'R20' in sentence]

Comment: Hola. Hmm ¿cabe la posibilidad de que algunos códigos de reclamos estén en minúsculas? Tipo R20m224920

Answer (score 3):

Cómo estás? Lo que podes intentar es simplemente convertir el string en una lista separándolos por palabras como muestro acá:

```
string = 'CONSUMIDOR INDICA QUE PROVEEDOR A UN NO DA CUMPLIMENTO A RESPUESTA DEL CASO N? R2020M3458452',
lista = string.split(" ")
print(lista)
```

Esto daria como resultado algo asi:

```
['CONSUMIDOR', 'INDICA', 'QUE', 'PROVEEDOR', 'A', 'UN', 'NO', 'DA', 'CUMPLIMENTO', 'A', 'RESPUESTA', 'DEL', 'CASO', 
'N?', 'R2020M3458452']
```

Entonces ahora ya tenemos todas las palabras separadas, asi que podes confirmar cuales son un código o no de la siguiente forma:

```
for palabra in palabras:
    if palabra[0:3] == "R20":
        print(palabra)
```

Esto daria como resultado algo asi:

```
'R2020M3458452'
```

Que es exactamente lo que vos buscas!

Con esto espero haber resuelto tus dudas, pero igualmente acá te paso el código para que sea mas sencillo de entender. Lo implemente con una función:

```
l = [
    'CONSUMIDOR INDICA QUE PROVEEDOR A UN NO DA CUMPLIMENTO A RESPUESTA DEL CASO N? R2020M3458452',
    'CONSUMIDOR INDICA INCUMPLIMIENTO DE PARTE DEL PROVEEDOR R2019M3454327 YA QUE SIGUEN REALIZANDO LLAMADAS A LOS NUMEROS INDICADOS EN EL RECLAMO .',
    'CONSUMIDORA INDICA QUE PROVEEDOR NO HA DADO CUMPLIMIENTO A SU RECLAMO N? R2019W3426996 , NO HA REALIZADO DEVOLUCION DEL DINERO'
]




def getCodigo(string):
    palabras = string.split(" ")
    for palabra in palabras:
        if palabra[0:3] == "R20":
            return palabra


for e in l:
    print(getCodigo(e))
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!, probaré con tu método :D